# Differences between Static Binding and Dynamic Binding

Tags: oop

I'd like to know if there's any difference between static/dynamic binding and early/late binding?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, they are basically different ways of referring to the same concepts.

Given a simple hierarchy like this:

```
class Phone {
    ...
}

class iPhone extends Phone {
    public boolean isExpensive() {
         return true;
    }
}

class Wileyfox extends Phone {
    public boolean isExpensive() {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Early/Static binding is when types and which types methods are called upon at compile time:

```
iPhone phone = new iPhone();
phone.isExpensive();
```

When calling isExpensive() method here, the compiler already knows that it needs to bind a type iPhone to the phone variable at compile time.

Late/Dynamic binding is when the compiler is not able to figure out who is going to be calling at compile time, but at runtime:

```
public boolean canAfford(Phone phone) {
    return !phone.isExpensive();
}
```

In this case, the compiler is not able to determine it until the code is actually being run.